# Does RAM affect the time taken to sort an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance

I have an array of a 500k to million items to be sorted. Does going with a configuration of increased RAM be beneficial or not, say 8GB to 32GB or above. Im using a node.JS/mongoDB environment.

Comment: How big is one item (an array of bytes isn't the same as an array of structures), and how big are the CPU's caches?

Comment: An item is an object with 5 keys. As fast as CPU cache I use i3 with 4mb or 6mb, but it's not extendable like ram I think?

Comment: I don'r know what a "key" is (recently I've been working with RSA4096 encryption keys but they're uncommon). If the total size of the array (or size of key in bytes * 5 * 1 million entries) is larger than the size of the largest cache; and if the array is accessed using a "not easy to predict pattern" (making it hard for CPU to prefetch the data from RAM into cache); then there might or might not be a benefit to either increasing the RAM bandwidth by increasing the number of memory channels used (by using more RAM slots), or by finding faster RAM (e.g. replacing DDR4-1800 with DDR4-2400 or...)

Comment: @Brendan key in the sense javascript object key-value pairs. thanks but there is not much i can do to increase the cpu cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding RAM for an operation like that would only make a difference if you have filled up the available memory with everything that was running on your computer and the OS was swapping data out to disk to make room for your sort operation.  Chances are, if that was happening, you would know because your computer would become pretty sluggish.

So, you just need enough memory for the working set of whatever applications you're running and then enough memory to hold the data you are sorting.  Adding additional memory beyond that will not make any difference.

If you had an array of a million numbers to be sorted in Javascript, that array would likely take (1,000,000 * 8 bytes per number) + some overhead for a JS data structure = ~8MB.  If your array values were larger than 8 bytes, then you'd have to account for that in the calculation, but hopefully you can see that this isn't a ton of memory in a modern computer.

If you have only an 8GB system and you have a lot of services and other things configured in it and are perhaps running a few other applications at the time, then it's possible that by the time you run nodejs, you don't have much free memory.  You should be able to look at some system diagnostics to see how much free memory you have.  As long as you have some free memory and are not causing the system to do disk swapping, adding more memory will not increase performance of the sort.

Now, if the data is stored in a database and you're doing some major database operation (such as creating a new index), then it's possible that the database may adjust how much memory it can use based on how much memory is available and it might be able to go faster by using more RAM.  But, for a Javascript array which is already all in memory and is using a fixed algorithm for the sort, this would not be the case.

Comment: thanks. It was really helpful and understandable in simple terms

Comment: @PrithiviRaj - To summarize, for a fixed in-memory sorting operation like this, you need enough memory to avoid OS disk swapping, but adding more beyond that will not make any difference.